# Connect usb camera to gpio pins

Tags: gpio, usb, webcam

Is there a way to connect usb camera to gpio pins? The reason doing so is the inconvenient location of usb ports, hence my custom box for raspberry pi needs to be expanded just for usb connectors. I understand that there are many usb ports already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physically, glue, solder, blu-tack.

However there is no way to use the Pi's gpio to provide a USB bus so there is no point.

So the answer is no.